# What does {} mean in the xargs command?

Tags: find, xargs

I want to move 1000000 files from a sources folder  to destination folder using the this command:

```
find /pacs/ccn15/ccn15_input/ccn1/(sources path) -name 'CDRCCN*' \
 | head -100 |xargs -I mv '{}' /pacs/ccn10/ccn10_input/ccn1/(destination path)
```

it is working fine but I'm not able to find out here what is the meaning of '{}'.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com, but see the man page for `find`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is a kind of placeholder for the output text we get from the previous command in the pipe. See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) page which explains it.